# Is my hyperledger peer make successful?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/ and using Options 1 i.e. vagrant development environment.When I run make membersrvc && membersrvc i get below message :

```
build/bin/membersrvc
CGO_CFLAGS=" " CGO_LDFLAGS="-lrocksdb -lstdc++ -lm -lz -lbz2 -lsnappy"    
GOBIN=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -
ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/metadata.Version=0.7.0-snapshot-
131b36c" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc
Binary available as build/bin/membersrvc
```

I assume membersrvc is running because "ps -a | grep membersrvc" returns

```
2486 pts/0    00:00:01 membersrvc
```

After this I ran "make peer" and got this :

```
Building docker javaenv-image
docker build -t hyperledger/fabric-javaenv build/image/javaenv
Sending build context to Docker daemon 44.03 kB
Step 1 : FROM openjdk:8
 ---> 96cddf5ae9f1
Step 2 : RUN wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-
bin.zip                    -P /tmp --quiet
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3dbbd6c16d7e
Step 3 : RUN unzip -qo /tmp/gradle-2.12-bin.zip -d /opt && rm /tmp/gradle-
2.12-b                   in.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd1d42253704
Step 4 : RUN ln -s /opt/gradle-2.12/bin/gradle /usr/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 248e99587f37
Step 5 : ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 27105db40f7a
Step 6 : ENV USER_HOME_DIR "/root"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03f5e84bf9ce
Step 7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref   && curl -fsSL 
http                   ://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-
3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_V                   ERSION-
bin.tar.gz     | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1   && ln -                   
s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
 ---> Running in 6ec30acda848
```

This stays on the window forever and nothing happens after this.

After this i try to run "peer node start --peer-chaincodedev" in another window
but i get below error:

```
No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
```

Why is not my peer created yet?

Comment: Here are the full logs of 'make peer' command
[link](http://pastebin.com/C8NyJUgg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PySa - a correct build of the Peer will drop you back to the cmd line and if you then issue the cmd `peer` it will show you the help / switches. To make / build the memberservices and peer all you have to do is the following:

1. vagrant up
2. ssh into the machine
3. `cd /hyperledger`
4. `make membersrvc`
5. `make peer` - this can take a LOOOOONG time depending on your
   machine & internet connection - the process has to download a LOT of
   data to complete correctly.

Once the above is done I would also strongly suggest you run `make unit-test` and when that's done `make behave` - again these will take a long to run but assuming all is well by the time it's done you'll be able to run `membersrvc` and `peer node start` (each in their own terminal windows) without problems...

FYI - the memberservices does NOT report anything to the console - the peer however does...

Comment: The Loooong time part was the crux, i mean i tried make peer multiple times , everytime maybe i waited around 15-20 mins. Suddenly it started working. Maybe the download happened in shifts.